# NSArray indexOfObject returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Any idea why can't I get the index of an object that I'm sure is exist in the array? Instead, I'm getting nil..

```
(lldb) po newItem
<ReceiptItem: 0x16a428b0>

(lldb) po self.items
<__NSArrayM 0x169bf0e0>(
<ReceiptItem: 0x16a428b0>
)

(lldb) po [self.items indexOfObject:newItem]
<nil>
```

Thanks

Comment: `indexOfObject` sends `isEqual` to all objects in the array until one `isEqual` returns `true`. It might be possible that `ReceiptItem` overwrites the `isEqual` and always returns `false` - is that class written by you or someone else who might have done that?

Comment: @luk2302 Interesting, i'll check it out

Comment: @Yossi as "luk" asked is that class written by you ? or what ?

Comment: try it like this   (lldb) p (NSInteger) [self.items 
   indexOfObject:newItem];

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`-indexOfObject:` returns an integer of type `NSUInteger`, not an object reference. Therefore you should not use `po` (print object) debugger command, but `p`.

It returns `0`, not `nil`, what means that it found the object at the first position of the array. If it would not find the object, `-indexOfObject:` would return `NSNotFound`.

> The lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to anObject. If none of the objects in the array is equal to anObject, returns NSNotFound.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
(lldb) p (NSUInteger)[self.items indexOfObject:newItems];
```